# Iterate on JSON and add buttons in React

Tags: javascript, reactjs, loops

I'm new on React and I have a problem in this code:

```
class Tests extends React.Component {

   async getTests() {
    var url = "http://127.0.0.1:100/getTestList"
    var buttons=[];
    const resp = await fetch(url);
    const data = await resp.json();

    for(let pkg in data){ 
        console.log(pkg);
        for (let cls in data[pkg]){
            console.log(cls);

            for (var i = 0; i < data[pkg][cls].length; i++) {
                let m= data[pkg][cls][i];
                buttons.push(<button value={cls}>{m}</button>);
            }
        }
    }

    return buttons;

}
render(){
    return(
        <div>
            <h4>Using .map()</h4>
            {this.getTests()}

        </div>
    )
}

}//fine classe

// ========================================

ReactDOM.render(
  <Tests />,
  document.getElementById('root')

);
```

I take correctly JSON Response from POST service, iterate correctly the JSON for to have an array of buttons with value and text but I have this error on Chrome:

> Error: Objects are not valid as a React child (found: [object Promise]). If you meant to render a collection of children, use an array instead.
>       in div (at src/index.js:95)
>       in Tests (at src/index.js:108)

Some Tips?
Thanks
Regards

Comment: getTest returns a promise, not an array of react components.

Comment: how convert this in array?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would use a function component with `useState` and `useEffect` for this case. In `useEffect` you can fetch your data from the endpoint then using `.map()` you can represent your buttons from the array what you instantiate with `useState`.

Please see the following solution which might resolve the issue:

```
const Tests = () => {
   const [buttons, setButtons] = useState([]);

   useEffect(() => {      
      async getTests() {
         const url = 'http://127.0.0.1:100/getTestList';
         const resp = await fetch(url);
         const data = await resp.json();
         const fetchedButtons = [];

         for (let pkg in data) { 
            for (let cls in data[pkg]) {
                for (var i = 0; i < data[pkg][cls].length; i++) {
                    let m = data[pkg][cls][i];
                    fetchedButtons.push(<button value={cls}>{m}</button>);
                }
            }
         }

         setButtons(fetchedButtons);
      }

      getTests();   
   }, []);

   return <div>
       <h4>Using.map()</h4>
       {/* here mapping the buttons array */}
       {
          buttons && buttons.map(e => e);          
       }
   </div>
}
```

I hope this helps!

Answer (score 1):

`getTests()` is an async function and it will always return a promise object. React is complaining because you are passing a promise object to the render method.

You could store the api response in a state, and set the state in `getTests` method. React will update the `ui` on  state update.

Few changes in the code.

1. Create state
2. Run the `getTests()` in `componentDidMount` method.
3. Loop over the values in render method.

**Example:**

```
class Tests extends React.Component {
    constructor(props) {
        super(props);
        this.state = {
            buttons: []
        }
    }
    async getTests() {
        var url = "http://127.0.0.1:100/getTestList"
        var buttons = [];
        const resp = await fetch(url);
        const data = await resp.json();
        for (let pkg in data) {
            console.log(pkg);
            for (let cls in data[pkg]) {
                console.log(cls);
                for (var i = 0; i < data[pkg][cls].length; i++) {
                    let m = data[pkg][cls][i];
                    buttons.push({ value: cls, displayName: m });
                }
            }
        }
       this.setState( () => {
            return {
                buttons
            }
        });
    }
    async componentDidMount() {
        await getTests();
    }
    render() {
        return (
            <div>
                <h4>Using .map()</h4>
                {this.state.buttons.map(button => <button key={button.value} value={button.value}>{button.displayName}</button>) }
            </div>
        )
    }
}//fine classe
// ========================================
ReactDOM.render(
    <Tests />,
    document.getElementById('root')
);
```

Or you could use a functional component for this.

```
const ButtonGroup = () => {
    const [buttons, setButtons] = useState([]);

    useEffect(() => {
        await getTests();
    }, []);

    async function getTests() {
        const url = 'http://127.0.0.1:100/getTestList';
        const resp = await fetch(url);
        const data = await resp.json();
        const buttonData = [];
        for (let pkg in data) {
            for (let cls in data[pkg]) {
                for (var i = 0; i < data[pkg][cls].length; i++) {
                    let m = data[pkg][cls][i];
                    buttonData.push({ value: cls, displayName: m });
                }
            }
        }
        setButtons(buttonData);
    }

    return (
        <div>
            <h4>Using.map()</h4>
            {buttons.map(button =>
                (
                    <button key={button.value} value={button.value}>{button.displayName}</button>
                )
            )}
        </div>
    );
}

export default ButtonGroup;
```

Comment: You forgot to setState at the end of getTests, Make getTest an arrow so it's bound to this and do `this.setState({buttons})`

Comment: `async getTests() {` should be `getTest = async () => {` arrow functions are bound to `this` so you don't have to do `this.getTest = this.getTest.bind(this)` in the constructor. You should call it with `this.getTests()`

Comment: Yes with await this.getTests() work but i have this error after:
Each child in a list should have a unique "key" prop.

Comment: yes, do you have any id with each record in the json, you have to pass a unique key in each option.

Comment: Currently I am using the `option.value` as the key, but not sue if it will have unique value.

Answer (score -1):

this error is expected.
From your code, getTest method returns an array of buttons.
You cannot render an array or an object from a react component.

Instead you can

1. make buttons a state variable,
2. set state after you prepare a local array in your getTest method.
3. use math method to render the button tag that you defined in array.

Comment: you need to study and understand react anatomy and implement it.